# Remove extra ASCII symbol rendering in PDF

Tags: vb.net, pdf, ascii, abcpdf9

I have a user that is storing a 'registered trademark' symbol in her name in our database and when we retrieve it when the database it renders correctly, but when we actually place it onto the website itself in HTML it renders with an extra 'A' symbol in front of it:

[image]

You can see above the database value compared to what is rendered in the PDF file. I can access the database value in the backend and edit it through vb code but I am really not sure how or what the code would be to do that as I don't want to remove all ASCII characters just the extra symbol being generated and rendered in the PDF.

Any idea how to do this would be great.

Comment: It looks UTF-8'ish. You should unify the expected and applied encodings for your database access code.

Comment: You may have to check the encoding of your html page output aswell (`meta Charset="xxx"` or `meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="xxx"`) ASCII is old (that's my opinion, but that's because not every names could be written in ASCII, since I live in a non english native language country) UTF-8 is very good IMHO and still handles ASCII well. UTF16/32 has the Big Endian/Little thing that can be very tricky at some point. UTF32 is too heavy on memory and definately need binary compression...

Answer (score 1):

I think the Main-Problem is that you generate wrong HTML-Code by just inserting your Database-Result-Strings into your Website

You can encode your Database String to HTML by using the HtmlEncode-Function from HttpUtility in .NET

Here is an Example from vb.net

```
myEncodedString = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myString)
```

If you use "myEncodedString" inside your WebPage you'll get no additional Characters and a valid HTML-Code.

Comment: thanks for the heads up, i'll double check through the code to see if there is encoding being done as this isn't 'my' application and usually there is a lot of encoding/decoding going on.  I think it also has to do with us using ABCpdf to render these pdf's I am researching that as well.

Comment: i tried using htmlencode, but i believe the issue is that the value wasn't encoded prior to being inserted into the database so using it as an htmlencode doesn't work, still renders the same